# code signing is required for product iOS after changing Project Name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Since I've changed the project name (Packaging -> Product name) of my project for release on app store i'm getting the code signing error(CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.0'). I've deleted all provisioning, all certificate and reissued them. But it doesn't help a thing....

I'm trying the whole day but nothing helps. Please help!

Thnx

ps. I have the problem if i use the archive function. Testing on the iPhone doesn't give any problems

Comment: CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.0'

Answer (score 5):

*CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.0'*

This error occurs for the simple reason that you don't have the "target" code-signing-identity fields set. If you just set the project-level values then they're not pushed down to the target. You need to explicitly set the "target". This solved my problem.

It's not that your profile and certificate are out of sync. As the error says "code signing is required". This indicates that you have not signed the app.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

if there is error like CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS X.X') and if you are using Xcode 4.2 and 4.3 SDK than probably  following could be a one kind of solution..If you have changed the provisioning profile or changed the code signing identity configuration due to changes while submitting the app or a new version or added a new code sign identity configuration. This error happens when the provision is not matching the bundle id & profile, you can do "Edit Scheme" (just after the run button double click on the project name), Do Edit Scheme.....follow image below

[image]
Select your code signing identity profile on the left, like archive and check the right hand side build configuration is matching & you have selected the Code Signing Identity based on the info.plist bundle setting & matching distribution profile, which is present.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I had this problem and your solution fixed it!  It was completely non-obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think your bundle identifier changed with the app name-change, so you will need to recover it.

1. Double-click the project file, then the target; look in the section called "Summary".
2. Change the first text field, named "Identifier", to the identifier of your app in the Developer Portal.

Comment: Ok! Thnx, where can I find the identifier of my app in the developer-portal?

Comment: login, top right "Member Center" -> "IOS Provisioning Portal" -> "App IDs"  -> Search your App -> click edit
Alternatively it is the Text which is at the Identifier and overwrite the new name with the old.   
As example "com.company.newName" in "com.company.oldName"

Comment: Mine doesn't say edit Alternatively. I can click details.. but I don't seem to find any. I've searched an older version of my code where the identifier isn't changed yet. I've changed everything back in my project to the old one.. but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after a source control update, the "Active scheme" was changed to "iOS Device". Changing it back to iPhone X.Y Simulator fixed the problem.